# How to prevent # at the end of URL in a BootStrap Drop-down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this link:

```
<a href="#" id="myBtn"><i class="icon-user"></i><span>Add user</span></a>
```

I use `preventDefault()` and `return false` to avoid the `#` at the end of my address. And it works perfectly. The problem is when I do the same with Bootstrap's dropdown. If I leave return false it doesn't add the `#` at the end as supposed, but it also prevents the dropdown from disappearing as it would if I remove `return false`.
This is my dropdown code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="ddBtn">
    <i class="icon-wrench"></i><span>Parent Item<b class="caret"></b></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="ddSonBtn">Child item</a></li>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#ddSonBtn").click(function () {
    //some code

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there a solution for this?

**I am using**

```
Bootstrap 2
jQuery
```

Thanks.

Comment: ...and your Javascript code?

Comment: @MassivePenguin nothing different than the usual, but I updated my question with your request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may or may not be well documented, but there's no need to call both `preventDefault()` **and** `return false;` in jQuery events.

**EDIT**: From jQuery's `on` docs: "Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`" ( http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler )

`return false;` is the equivalent of `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation();`

`preventDefault` prevents the default behavior of an element - such as a submit button submitting a form, an anchor navigating to a specific `href`, etc.

`stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the DOM. Meaning, events won't be triggered on parent elements of the target element.

Pick and choose which you need when working with Events. In your situation, you probably only need to call `preventDefault` in your Dropdown's click handler.

Also, in your code, the use of `return` in a function's scope is the last line of execution. Any code after it will **not** be executed when the function is run.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you, but actually not, if I call only `preventDefault`, as I said in my question, it adds the `#` at the end of the address. Thanks

Comment: I already tried to use only `return false` it does work, not adding the `#`, but it stills prevents the dropdown from disappearing. :(

Comment: @eestein Well I'm not sure it should be adding the `#` still. If you're binding to the right element and doing things correctly, it will work right. Anyways, the HTML you provided doesn't match up to your Javascript. You are binding the click event to the element with an `id` of "xptoBtn", but I don't see that element in your HTML. You shouldn't use `return false;` because it actually calls `stopPropagation()`, which stops the bubbling and therefore doesn't let Bootstrap handle the event properly. You should only use `preventDefault` but in the right place. Please post your actual code

Comment: I updated according to your request. But I didn't say that it was adding the `#` at the end, please re-read my commment. What I said is that it works, not adding the `#` at the end, but it stills prevent the dropdown from disappearing after the click. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ian, I'm sorry I misread your comment. I just retried with `preventDefault` and it is happening the same as I said in my first comment. I does allow bootstrap to hide the dropdown, but it adds the `#` at the end.

Comment: @eestein Your binding the event with `$("#ddSonBtn").click(function () {`, but you need to set the event parameter. Use `$("#ddSonBtn").click(function (e) {` instead - notice the `e`

Comment: @eestein No problem :) Also, you might want to call `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of your event handler. That way, in case any errors occur in `//some code`, the event should always be prevented (since it's called first)

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks again =D

Answer (score 14):

According to the Bootstrap docs:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

it is necessary to replace `href` by `data-target` attribute, i.e.

```
<a data-target="#" id="myBtn"><i class="icon-user"></i><span>Add user</span></a>
```

I believe it is more "bootstrapish" way to do things rather than suppressing event handlers or manually manipulating the show/hide behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am using Bootstrap collapse and the text anchor wasn't causing the #anchor to get appended to the browser URL, however, the font awesome icon with the same anchor was causing the #anchor to get appended so I swapped the href for the data-target and all is right!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `#` value from the `href` attribute. It's valid HTML to leave `href` empty.

```
<a href="" id="myBtn"><i class="icon-user"></i><span>Add user</span></a>
```

Comment: Now as this is downvoted I'm interested in why this is not a good solution. For me, it works like a charm in all current browsers and just as expected. But maybe I'm not seeing the whole picture, so I'm curious ...

Comment: Although I absolutely no NOT condone the use of the javascript pseudo protocol, the empty href is a proper solution. Helped me out--thanks!

Comment: @JAAulde Thanks, you're right, my post read as if the javascript solution was equal to the empty href while my intention was to provide just another alternative if the empty href was not an option for some reason. After thinking about it again, I decided to remove this alternative (as you have confirmed now that the better/cleaner solution does what it should anyway).

Comment: Note that if you remove the `#` value, you'll need to explicitly disable the link with `e.preventDefault()`, otherwise the page will reload.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Bootstrap + jQuery:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("open")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after much searching realised it was my own error.  I had an incorrect link to the bootstrap js file (the integrity hash was incorrect) and therefore didn't load.  This caused the dropdown not to work on some pages.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this way and it worked. The example (coffee script) is like this;

```
jQuery ->
  $('.your_mark ul.dropdown-menu li').click ->
    # Do what you want
    $(this.parentElement.parentElement).removeClass('open')
    return false
```

1. Close the dropdown menu manually by removing css class 'open' from the btn-group div.
2. Return false to avoid having # in your url.